# Using tkinter combobox selected value as a parameter in a sql query to effect the options in another combobox

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, combobox, parameter-passing

I have multiple engagements for each client so what I'm trying to do is make it easier to select the appropriate engagement. I'm trying to do this by having 2 comboboxes, one that displays the client list, and one that displays the engagement list. I want the engagement list, however, to be narrowed down by whichever client was selected. I know I'm passing the parameter correctly for the engagement dropdown, but when I try to set engagement1['values'] = engagement_dropdown(). I receive TypeError: engagement_dropdown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'client_dropdown'. When I try adding client_dropdown within engagement_dropdown, I get pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 1 paramter markers, but 72 parameters were supplied', 'HY000'). What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sys
import os
import backend
import pyodbc
from functools import partial

global conn

conn = pyodbc.connect(
    Driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',
    Server = 'server',
    Database = 'db',
    Trusted_Connection = 'Yes')

def client_dropdown():
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT [ClientName] FROM TimeEntryDB.dbo.DimClientEngagements GROUP BY [ClientName] ORDER BY [ClientName] ASC")
    data = []
    for client_list in cur.fetchall():
        data.append(client_list[0])
    return data

def engagement_dropdown(client_dropdown):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT [EngagementName] FROM TimeEntryDB.dbo.DimClientEngagements WHERE [ClientName] = ?", (client_dropdown()))
    data = []
    for engagement_list in cur.fetchall():
        data.append(engagement_list[0])
    return data

screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("500x300")
screen.title("Time Entry Application")
heading = Label(text = "Review and Approve Time Entries and Timesheets", bg = "blue", fg = "white", width = "500", height = "2")
heading.pack()

#Client field
engagement_label = Label(text = "Client",)
engagement_label.place(x = 15, y = 50)

selected_client = StringVar()
client1 = ttk.Combobox(screen, width = 20, textvariable = selected_client, state = 'readonly')
client1['values'] = client_dropdown()
client1.place(x= 15, y = 70)

#Engagement field
engagement_label = Label(text = "Engagement",)
engagement_label.place(x = 200, y = 50)

selected_engagement = StringVar()
engagement1 = ttk.Combobox(screen, width = 40, textvariable = selected_engagement, state = 'readonly')
engagement1['values'] = engagement_dropdown()
engagement1.place(x= 200, y = 70)

screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is you are confusing passing arguments into functions for you to use within the function and using variables inside of a function. The way you wrote the function you are asking you it requires an argument and you aren't passing one in your post. I've modified the function call to pass a value in the argument declared and use it within the function. This should resolve your problem.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sys
import os
import backend
import pyodbc
from functools import partial

global conn

conn = pyodbc.connect(
    Driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',
    Server = 'server',
    Database = 'db',
    Trusted_Connection = 'Yes')

def client_dropdown():
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT [ClientName] FROM TimeEntryDB.dbo.DimClientEngagements GROUP BY [ClientName] ORDER BY [ClientName] ASC")
    data = []
    for client_list in cur.fetchall():
        data.append(client_list[0])
    return data

def engagement_dropdown(client_val):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sql_val = "SELECT [EngagementName] FROM TimeEntryDB.dbo.DimClientEngagements WHERE [ClientName] = " + str(client_val)
    cur.execute(sql_val)
    data = []
    for engagement_list in cur.fetchall():
        data.append(engagement_list[0])
    return data

screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("500x300")
screen.title("Time Entry Application")
heading = Label(text = "Review and Approve Time Entries and Timesheets", bg = "blue", fg = "white", width = "500", height = "2")
heading.pack()

#Client field
engagement_label = Label(text = "Client",)
engagement_label.place(x = 15, y = 50)

selected_client = StringVar()
client1 = ttk.Combobox(screen, width = 20, textvariable = selected_client, state = 'readonly')
client1['values'] = client_dropdown()
client1.place(x= 15, y = 70)

#Engagement field
engagement_label = Label(text = "Engagement",)
engagement_label.place(x = 200, y = 50)

selected_engagement = StringVar()
engagement1 = ttk.Combobox(screen, width = 40, textvariable = selected_engagement, state = 'readonly')
engagement1['values'] = engagement_dropdown(selected_client)
engagement1.place(x= 200, y = 70)

screen.mainloop()
```